# I need to custom format a code analysis report generated by PMD

Tags: html, command-line, pmd

I want to edit the formatting of the html that is produced by this command:

C:\tmp\pmd-bin-5.1.0\pmd\bin>pmd -d c:\data\pmd\pmd\test-data\Unused1.java -f xml -R rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml

where it says "-f xml", I replaced xml with html and I want to edit the html code before it finalizes the page.

I don't know where the command is writing the code for the page but I want to at least change some of the parameters permanently so that it will generate the desired format every time.

Answer (score 3):

If you know [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp), then you can probably use the `xslt` renderer. That renderer outputs the report using the XML formatter, then processes it using a user-provided XSLT stylesheet. This may be used to produce a HTML page in any format you like for the report.

For example:

```
C:\tmp\pmd-bin-5.1.0\pmd\bin>pmd -d c:\data\pmd\pmd\test-data\Unused1.java ^
  -R rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml ^
  -f xslt ^
  -P xsltFilename=pmd_report.xsl  ^
  -r report.html
```

where `pmd_report.xslt` is your stylesheet. An example for such a stylesheet can be found [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-core/src/main/resources/pmd-nicerhtml.xsl), which is the default stylesheet if you don't provide an explicit `xsltFilename`.

The generated HTML file will be at the location `report.html`.